# How to get the rows that satisfies the most conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the table:

```
ID  COD1  COD2  COD3  COD4  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3
--  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
1   ABC   AB    NULL  NULL  1     2     3   
2   NULL  NNN   NULL  AAA   2     4     5   
3   ABC   AB    PP    AAA   3     2     4  
4   ABC   AB    PP    AAA   1     3     4
```

I need to get the rows that satisfies most of the conditions (COD columns)

- EXAMPLE 1: Get all rows where COD1=ABC, COD2=AB, COD3=AAA and COD4=BBB, must return the row 1
- EXAMPLE 2: Get all rows where COD1=ABC, COD2=AB, COD3=PP and COD4=AAA, must return the row 3 and 4

See below DDL and DML:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TEST AS
(
    ID      NUMBER,
    COD1    VARCHAR2(100),
    COD2    VARCHAR2(100),
    COD3    VARCHAR2(100),
    COD4    VARCHAR2(100),
    VAR1    NUMBER,
    VAR2    NUMBER,    
    VAR3    NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TEST_X (ID, COD1, COD2, COD3, COD4, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3) VALUES (1, 'ABC', 'AB', NULL, NULL, 1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO TEST_X (ID, COD1, COD2, COD3, COD4, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3) VALUES (2, NULL, 'NNN', NULL, 'AAA', 2, 4, 5);
INSERT INTO TEST_X (ID, COD1, COD2, COD3, COD4, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3) VALUES (3, 'ABC', 'AB', 'PP', 'AAA', 3, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO TEST_X (ID, COD1, COD2, COD3, COD4, VAR1, VAR2, VAR3) VALUES (4, 'ABC', 'AB', 'PP', 'AAA', 1, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             dense_rank() over
                 (order by ((case when cod1 = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) +
                            (case when cod2 = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) +
                            (case when cod3 = 'AAA' then 1 else 0 end) +
                            (case when cod4 = 'BBB' then 1 else 0 end)
                           ) desc
                 ) as seqnum
      from t
     )
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you only want one row in the case of ties, change the `dense_rank()` to `row_number()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your Question, you said:
EXAMPLE 3: Get all rows where COD1=ABC, COD2=AB, COD3=PP and COD4=AAA, must return the row 4,

How come it will only retrieve Row 4, when Row 3 also satisfies the conditions?